# Как обозначить i+2 элемент массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите. Есть программа, которая расшифровывает нужный мне шифр по типу:

```
А -- В (толко с инглишем)
Г -- Е
```

Буква вводится с клавиатуры и сравнивается с буквой в алфавите (который представлен в массиве) и, если введеная буква совпадает с i- элементом, то в другой (пустой) массив добавляется буква, идущая через 1 от этот i в алфавите, то есть i+2.
Но у меня вылетает :
Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Как правильно обозначить i+2 элемент?

http://ideone.com/Kcv64C

```
n = 1
while n:
x = (input('х : '))
exp = []
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
     'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
for i in a:

    if x == i:
        ex = i + 2
        exp.append(ex)
    elif x == 'y':
        exp.append('a')
if x == ' ':
    exp.append(x)
elif x == '.':
    exp.append(x)
print(exp)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это называется "[шифр Цезаря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F)".

Можно использовать функцию `enumerate`, чтобы знать текущую позицию в списке.

```
for i, char in enumerate(a):
    if x == char:
        exp.append(a[i + 2])
```

Чтобы не вываливалось IndexError в конец массива и не приходилось костыли приписывать, можно использовать типичный для таких случаев трюк с оператором `%`, чтобы индекс не выходил за предел:

```
for i, char in enumerate(a):
    if x == char:
        exp.append(a[(i + 2) % 26])
```

Если вы хотите проверить является символ буквой, то можно воспользоваться следующим методом, а не писать на каждый символ свое условие:

```
x.isalpha()
```

К слову: вам не обязательно пробегать по списку, ведь у букв есть известный порядок. Вы можете узнать номер буквы в таблице юникода с помощью функции `ord()` - прописные латинские начинаются с 97 позиции (`a`) и следуют до 122 (`z`). Затем прибавляем к номеру 2 и узнаем какая буква находится на этой позиции через функцию `chr()`. Только нужно опять быть аккуратным и не выскочить за границы 97-122, а также корректно обрабатывать заглавные.

Comment: Я бы вместо `exp.append(a[(i + 2) % 26])` просто добавил лишних пару элементов в массив: `a = ['a','b',...,'z','a','b']`, а цикл гнал по `a[0:26]`

Comment: можно [используя `str.translate()` метод реализовать Caesar шифр (`shift == 2`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26371777/4279).

Answer (score -1):

А вообще я бы сделал так:

```
crypt = {'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'e', ... 'x': 'z', 'y': 'a', 'z': 'b'}


def crypt_str(s):
    r = ""
    for c in s:
        try:
            r += crypt[c]
        except KeyError:
            r += c
    return r

print crypt_str("any text")
```